# how kubernetes services route traffic to https

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

I have one external Service exposed on multiple ports, not in the same CLuster. Something like below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 9377
```

I am new to Kubernetes services.

1. My Question is how Kubernetes know which port to call when there is an incoming request for **my-service**. My assumption is it depends upon incoming Port requests received.

For e.g if their is an request on port 443, then it will hit the target port on 9377.

2. How can I create aliases in Kubernetes. Let us suppose I have incoming request for service A but I dont have service name "A". I have my service as name "B". I just want to use some aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Services are an abstract Kubernetes object, so it will always be available even if there are no target containers running.
Requests on my-service:443 will be sent to containers that have label `app: MyApp` on their port 9377, so your assumption is good.